# Passing a value from other form to active form

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Object from Form to Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781945/passing-object-from-form-to-form)

Good evening to all. I tried searching the google and found nothing that fits for my needs. I have a problem passing the value from second form to first active form. From second form i want to pass the value of textBox_Dbname.text to active form(always active) treeViewDbList.Nodes.Add() but i cant. i dont know how to fix this kind of issue. im still beginner in programming that need to learn more.
Please help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: And the long, long list of Related questions on your right aren't enough to give you a hint on where to start? =)

Comment: What are you using? Winforms/WPF/Asp.Net Webforms/MVC?

Comment: @J.Steen is right. I just picked the top one but this is asked several times a week here. Google first.

Comment: Here is a good article:
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Comment: Which also turn up when you start writing the title of your question, in the question-form.

Comment: i tried answers from the right like i said those are not fit to my needs. thanks for your concern.

Comment: this is what im looking for>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form

Answer (score -1):

Can u access the properties of the form where u need the value from? if yes u can create a property like the following:

```
public string TbText
{
   get{return textBox_Dbname.Text;}
}
```